# Hardware (cameras, headsets) for TEALS supported classrooms

Tags: secondary-education, ap-computer-science-a, ap-cs-principles

We have [TEALS](https://www.tealsk12.org) (a NGO which supports CS education in US with programs that team industry professionals with CS classrooms - both in person and remotely) distance learning support for our CS classes - industry mentors join the class remotely to help teach the class. I'd like to hear from others who are teaching in similar environments about what hardware they are using - especially in general terms:

- What features to look for.
- What makes the gear durable (or fragile).
- What do your students like - and what do they resist.
- Anything else that would help to guide choices of hardware to support a distance learning model.

The specific classes are AP CS A and AP CS Principles, if that matters.

Comment: What is TEALS (explain in question)?

Comment: (I have do Audio IT classes.) Get them to provide their own headphones: Those things get broken or stolen.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - They do, but there are two problems. For remote learning we need mics and the sets that kids own often don't have them and we have enough students who don't have the means to provide their own - so I'd like to provide some. I do encourage students to bring their own.